# How to automatically create a database with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am following a tutorial on creating a todo list app. I use the exact same code as in the video. For a to do list, we are creating a database, and when the person runs the code a database file called db.sqlite is created automatically. But when I run, it doesn't happen. Here is my code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('base.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>todo app</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>To do App</h1>
    <form action="">
        <div>
            <label for="title">Todo Title</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Todo....">
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help.

Comment: It was relate that you don't have permission to create a db.sqlite. Can you make create this file by ordinary means

Comment: To create the tables you need an application context. Put the call to create the tables in a with block in which you [push the application context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/appcontext/#manually-push-a-context). For some time now, the database is no longer created in the root directory of your application, but rather under the [instance folder](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/config/#instance-folders). Make sure you look in the correct directory to see if the file was created. Your example worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I tried this, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: here are the things you can check.
1. does the file already exist? if yes remove it
2. file permissions: make sure you have the right to read and write in the directory
3. installation of SQLite: make sure it is properly installed.
4. set app.debug = True before running your Flask application.

Answer (score 0):

In your app:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask
from os import path

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

def create_db(app):
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        print("Database tables created successfully.")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('base.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not path.exists('db.sqlite'):
        create_db(app)
    app.run(debug=True)
```